# Converting PHP FUNCTION from MySQL to MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, function

Have read this problem to death and recognise that this problem is probably a scope issue.

But, no matter what I've found, I still can't make it work... (plus being a newbie at this, not fully understand what "scope" really is)

What I've got so far..

```
<?php

class Database
{
var $onError = 0; 
var $longQuery = 0; 
var $errorFrom = 'email@domain.com';
var $db;
var $dbname;
var $host;
var $password;
var $queries;
var $result;
var $user;  
var $id;
var $id_name;
var $table_name;
var $columns = array();

function Database($host, $user, $password, $dbname)
{
    $this->host     = $host;
    $this->user     = $user;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->dbname   = $dbname;          
}

function connect($redirect = false)
{
     $this->queries = array();
     $this->db = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password,$this->dbname) or $this->notify(mysqli_error(), false, true);

}

function query($sql)
{
    //Set multiple queries
    $this->queries[] = $sql;
    //echo $sql;exit;
    $varStart = microtime();
    $this->result = mysqli_query($sql) or $this->notify(mysqli_error($this->result));

    $varStop = microtime();

    $varQueryExecutionTime = $varStop - $varStart;

    if(($longQuery != 0) && ($varQueryExecutionTime > $longQuery))
    {
        $msg  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . " @ " . date("Y-m-d H:ia") . "\n\n";
        $msg .= 'The following query took $varQueryExecutionTime to complete:\n\n';
        $msg .= $this->lastQuery() . "\n\n";
        $msg .= $this->queries() . "\n\n";

        @mail($this->errorTo, "Long Query " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $msg, "From: {$this->errorFrom}");
    }
    return $this->result;
}

//Rest of the other functions

}
```

I believe the MySQLi query should be

```
        $this->result = mysqli_query($CONNECTION_HERE, $sql) or $this->notify(mysqli_error($this->result));
```

I've tried

```
        $this->result = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql) or $this->notify(mysqli_error($this->result));
```

and

```
        $this->result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or $this->notify(mysqli_error($this->result));
```

but still get

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/..../classes/class_database_dbl.php on line 103

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/..../classes/class_database_dbl.php on line 103

The config.php has

```
  //Open a connection to Database
$objDatabase = new Database($arrConfig['dbHost'], $arrConfig['dbUser'], $arrConfig['dbPass'], $arrConfig['dbName']);
$objDatabase->connect();
```

in it...

Have done my best, but dismally failed....

Cheers

Comment: check if `$arrConfig` returns the associated values... May be it is the one which is off-Scope..

Comment: Done the var_dump($arrConfig);die(); straight after the opening <?php - Got the full array of correct info. Thing is, it all works using mysql. As soon as I started to try and use MySQLi - it broke... It's like NO information is being parsed to the section "function query($sql)" IE $this->db is NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the assistance.

Not fixed however, so will start re-writing from scratch when I get a chance.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For excample you have db class

```
 <?php
    class DB_class{
        protected $server = "localhost";
        protected $dbuser = "root";
        protected $dbpw = "";
        protected $db = "db";
        protected $con;

        function __construct() {
            $this->con = new mysqli($this->server,$this->dbuser,$this->dbpw, $this->db);
            $this->con->set_charset("utf8");
       }
    }
    ?>
```

Then you this class extend in another class where you need get data from db.

```
function getCategory(){
    DB_class::__construct();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
    $rs=$this->con->query($sql);
    while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){

        array_push($this->arrCategory, array('ID'=>$row['ID'], 'CategoryName'=>$row['category_name']));
    }
}
```

In my example all result I push in array, but you can this data simple show.

Comment: Thx Normis - but means double dutch to me. I am trying to use your example in what I have, but alas - I'm not good enough to understand what I need to do.  This class file handles multiple pages throughout the website, so I can't use a call like  $sql = "SELECT * FROM category";   There are 50-odd pages that call this class file, all with different sql statements...

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it's almost OK.

I noticed some issues:

1)

```
mysqli_query($this->db, $sql)
```

instead of

```
mysqli_query($sql)
```

2)

```
if(($this->longQuery != 0) && ($varQueryExecutionTime > $this->longQuery))
```

instead of

```
if(($longQuery != 0) && ($varQueryExecutionTime > $longQuery))
```

---

Besides of this, your code is good, and it works.

I also tried wrong DB credentials, and I got the same errors you did. So, check for `$arrConfig`, it's probably empty or wrong.

Just use a `var_dump($arrConfig);die();` to check it out.

Comment: Thx Joaquin - Changed as per your helpful advice.     Done the var_dump($arrConfig);die(); straight after the opening <?php - Got the full array of correct info.  Thing is, it all works using mysql. As soon as I started to try and use MySQLi - it broke...   It's like NO information is being parsed to the section "function query($sql)"  IE $this->db is NULL?

Comment: Have spent more time trying to fault correct..  Comes down to the variables not being recognised inside the class. I do a var_dump($arrConfig);die(); straight after the opening <?php and show s correct info.  BUT, trying to get the variables to work inside the class is the problem

Comment: Where are you using `$arrConfig`? Inside a method? If not, what happens if you var_dump  `$arrConfig` just before you do `new Database() `?

Comment: What is doing my head in is that this has been working fine for the last 5 years with MySQL.  So config.php variables are fine, the variables are going through to the class file fine.  So it must be a MySQLi thing.

Comment: Can you please `var_dump()` each parameter of the Database class Constructor? Thanks.

Comment: Ok...  This shows the EG user 

`function Database ($host, $user, $password, $dbname)
 {

  $this->host     = $host;
  $this->user     = $user;
  $this->password = $password;
  $this->dbname   = $dbname; 

                var_dump($user);die();
  }`

This shows NULL

`function connect($redirect = false)
 {
  var_dump($user);die;
  $this->queries = array();
  $this->db = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password ,$this->dbname);
 }`

Comment: Ok, this is just about debug. try this: `function Database ($host, $user, $password, $dbname) { /* all your assigments */ var_dump($this); }` and please post the ouput in the question, or in a pastebin and link it from here. (posting code or output in comments is quite not-good-looking)